# Minimum date from a list that is after dates from another list

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two set of dates, startdate and enddate inside a dataframe

For each startdate, I want to find the smallest enddate that's greater than the startdate.

My minimum example code is below but it is very slow, takes 20 seconds each run. Note in my example the date range is the same so a "shift" is possible here but not in my real data.

is there anyway to speed up the code?

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.DataFrame({'startdate':pd.date_range(start='2000-11-03', end='2021-10-01'),'enddate':pd.date_range(start='2000-11-03', end='2021-10-01')})
dates['mindate_after_startdate']=dates['startdate'].apply(lambda x: min(dates['enddate'][dates['enddate']>x],default=datetime.today().date()))
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for is pd.merge_asof() https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Answer (score 0):

figured it out using pd.merge_asof and direction='forward' argument.

Comment: I'm glad that you figured out a solution to your problem. If you can take a few minutes to add some more code details on your solution, that might help the next person who has this issue.